# How to exclude class with same name located in the footer?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

Here is a sample of the code:

```
<body>
  <div class="koko">content here</div>
  <footer>
    <div class="koko">content</div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Now, how to exclude the `koko` class, but only the one located in the `footer` element?

I tried this:

```css
.koko:not(footer.koko)
```

it didn't work.

I also tried:

```css
.koko:not(footer)
```

and

```css
.koko:not(.footer.koko)
```

but nothing helped. Any ideas?

Comment: try adding a space between footer and .koko: .koko:not(footer .koko)

Comment: You have an unclosed `footer` tag and no `footer` tag with class `koko`. There's a `div` within the `footer` which has this class. The comment above solves your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `>` direct cildren

```css
.koko {
  background: red
}
footer > .koko {
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="koko">content here</div>
<footer>
  <div class="koko">content</div>
</footer>
```

or you can use `:not`

```css
.wrap .koko {
  background: red
}
footer div:not(.koko) {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="koko">content here</div>
</div>
<footer>
  <div class="koko">content</div>
  <div>this will be red</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Yea buut I want to exclude it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of excluding the footer class, I included only the class in the body, like:

```
.lnd > .koko {css}
```

and it worked. Awesome

Comment: Sorry my first time posting. I am just editing custom CSS on a given post on wordpress. and the class I wanted excluded was from the theme.